# Load environment variables in rails app without restarting server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2

How can I make my rails app aware of the new environment variables after I have edited my `/etc/environment` file on my remote EC2 instance?

I frequently add new (minor) things in my `secrets.yml` but I don't want to restart my server for it, nor do I want to use an existing secret.

Comment: Down-voter care to comment?

Comment: Apparently the answer is, its not possible :(

Answer (score 3):

In linux every process inherits envvars from its parent process and the values are passed by value, not by reference. Also, they don't behave like closures. So, child process (your rails/ruby app process) will not get any new environment variables of its parent (the shell process where you started your rails/ruby app).

That's why it is not possible. However, you can use gems like [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) and [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) to watch some file with your environment variables and reload them when they are changed.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a line to your `config/spring.rb`:

```
Spring.watch "config/secrets.yml"
```

This will allow Spring to detect when changes have occurred in your secrets.yml file.

However, if you're actually asking about how to make your app aware that you've changed *environment variables* in a file, then it's not possible.  Config values may be detected in files, but environment variables are detected in the shell environment.  You have to load those into your shell for them to take any effect, and this would require stopping your server, sourcing the new changes into the environment, and starting the server again.

Understanding the difference between a config value in a file (.yml, .xml, .ini, etc) versus an environment variable in a shell script is important, because how it's applied and made usable is entirely different.